Implementing subscription models like TikTok and X(Twitter) on Android
I'm developing an Android app.
I want to include a subscription billing feature, but what I have in mind is a little different from the usual scenario.
Normally, I would list a few subscription products in the Google Play Console and let users subscribe to them in the app.
What I'd like to implement is a different approach, where app users can create their own subscription products in the app, and other users can subscribe to them.
Is it possible to implement this way?
The first thing I looked at was Tiktok and X (Twitter), and I saw possibilities.
In the snapshot below, you can see that the name of the subscription product is customized with the user's name.

(sorry for Korean text)
What they have in common is that they only offer one subscription, and we didn't find any cases where a user registered for multiple subscriptions.
I like to let users create 1-3 subscription products per user, but I haven't found any cases where more than one is up and running.
I was able to find the following API to dynamically create subscription products.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/monetization.subscriptions/create
I did a quick test and it created up to 1,000 products, but after 1,000, it started dropping an error that the limit was exceeded.
I sent a mail to Google asking about the maximum limit, but they said they couldn't tell me.
I was wondering how TikTok or X implemented this.
To summarize the question,

is it possible to implement recurring payments on Android in the form of user-created recurring payment products like TikTok and X?

How many recurring payment products can each user create (why do TikTok and X only offer one, or is there some kind of limitation?)

1,000 recurring payments seems to be the limit, how did TikTok and X get past that?


